# cannot install python pyo library in termux

Tags: python, android, termux, pyo

im trying to install python "pyo" library but it failed.

command :

```
python -m pip install --timeout=60 pyo
```

output :

```
.... (see full erorr massage at : [https://paste.quest/?ef43e5da487b4790#4Wawn8pxW3orqbHjaK8DY2WtyWFNjrSabvTLmuBh48Hp]) .....
aarch64-cpython-311/src/objects/tablemodule.o -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-strict-aliasing -O3 -g0 -DNDEBUG
      src/objects/tablemodule.c:8041:9: error: call to undeclared function 'shm_unlink'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       8041 |         shm_unlink(self->name);
            |         ^
      src/objects/tablemodule.c:8071:20: error: call to undeclared function 'shm_open'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       8071 |         self->fd = shm_open(self->name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
            |                    ^
      src/objects/tablemodule.c:8071:20: note: did you mean 'sf_open'?
      /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/sndfile.h:595:11: note: 'sf_open' declared here
        595 | SNDFILE*        sf_open         (const char *path, int mode, SF_INFO *sfinfo) ;
            |                 ^
      src/objects/tablemodule.c:8083:13: error: call to undeclared function 'shm_unlink'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       8083 |             shm_unlink(self->name);
            |             ^
      src/objects/tablemodule.c:8089:20: error: call to undeclared function 'shm_open'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       8089 |         self->fd = shm_open(self->name, O_RDWR, 0);
            |                    ^
      src/objects/tablemodule.c:8108:13: error: call to undeclared function 'shm_unlink'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       8108 |             shm_unlink(self->name);
            |             ^
      5 errors generated.
      error: command '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-android-clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyo
Failed to build pyo
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

output of "pkg show clang cmake python" :

```
Package: clang
Version: 17.0.6
Maintainer: @finagolfin
Installed-Size: 201 MB
Depends: libcompiler-rt, lld, llvm, ndk-sysroot, libllvm (= 17.0.6)
Breaks: libllvm (<< 16.0.0), clangd
Replaces: libllvm (<< 16.0.0), clangd
Homepage: https://clang.llvm.org/
Download-Size: 31.7 MB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: https://mirrors.cbrx.io/apt/termux/termux-main stable/main aarch64 Packages
Description: C language frontend for LLVM
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Package: cmake
Version: 3.28.2
Maintainer: @termux
Installed-Size: 44.8 MB
Depends: libarchive, libc++, libcurl, libexpat, jsoncpp, libuv, rhash, zlib
Recommends: clang, make
Homepage: https://cmake.org/
Download-Size: 6523 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: https://mirrors.cbrx.io/apt/termux/termux-main stable/main aarch64 Packages
Description: Family of tools designed to build, test and package software
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Package: python
Version: 3.11.6-1
Maintainer: @termux
Installed-Size: 62.9 MB
Provides: python3
Depends: gdbm, libandroid-posix-semaphore, libandroid-support, libbz2, libcrypt, libexpat, libffi, liblzma, libsqlite, ncurses, ncurses-ui-libs, openssl, readline, zlib

Recommends: python-ensurepip-wheels, python-pip
Suggests: python-tkinter
Breaks: python2 (<= 2.7.15), python-dev
Replaces: python-dev
Homepage: https://python.org/
Download-Size: 7909 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: https://mirrors.cbrx.io/apt/termux/termux-main stable/main aarch64 Packages
Description: Python 3 programming language intended to enable clear programs
```

termux Variables :

TERMUX_API_VERSION=0.50.1

TERMUX_MAIN_PACKAGE_FORMAT=debian

TERMUX_VERSION=0.118.0

Packages CPU architecture : aarch64

Updatable packages : All packages up to date

Android version : 10

please help me to install this library